# Unable to get value of the property 'elementType': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, typescript, web-essentials

I have the following code in a TypeScript file:

```
define('myModule', [], function () {

    var self = {
        init: function () {
            doSomething();
        }
    };

    var dayNames:string[] = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

    function doSomething () {
        var current = new Date();
        var day = dayNames[current.getDay()];
    }

    return self;
});
```

However it does not compile with Visual Studio 2012/Web Essentials 2012.

> Compile Error.  See error list for details  tsc.js(19148, 13)
>   Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property
>   'elementType': object is null or undefined

Strangely the same code seems to compile fine on the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/). I have checked the version of *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc.js* which is the current latest on CodePlex (0.8.3.0).

If I comment out the following line, it compiles fine:

```
var day = dayNames[current.getDay()];
```

And the following code block in isolation also compiles fine:

```
var dayNames:string[] = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

function doSomething () {
    var current = new Date();
    var day = dayNames[current.getDay()];
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move the definition of `dayNames` before the `self` declaration it compiles fine so it appears you're calling `doSomething()` before `dayNames` is defined.

Why this is the case, and why it doesn't generate a more helpful compiler error I'm not sure - I'd put that down to TypeScript still being alpha code. You may want to raise it as an issue on [CodePlex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic).

I have noticed a few other instances like this. For example if you have one class which extends another in the same file, you need to put the base class first, otherwise the compiler sometimes falls over.

Comment: Yes that compiles. Looking forward to an explanation!

Comment: Somebody else may have one, but unfortunately I don't.

Comment: +1 , like JcFx says self depends on doSomething which depends on dayNames. So I would put dayNames -> doSomething ->self . However dayname -> self ->doSomething works fine as well.

Comment: That's fine, but are we really expected to order our code based on dependencies like this? Seems like a serious limitation of the compiler and a backwards step in productivity/maintenance (which the language is meant to improve). Have raised the issue [here](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/981).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be resolved after updating to [TypeScript 0.9.0](https://typescript.codeplex.com/releases/view/105503).